# How to return a lubridate interval as whole days

Tags: r, lubridate

I have two dates, `start_date` and `end_date`, I have calculated the interval between them and I would like to show it as a whole number of days. I expect the code below to do this, but instead, it seems to be returning an interval instead, what am I doing wrong?

```
df <- tibble(start_date = '2020-02-27', end_date = '2020-03-17')

times <- df %>% mutate(hol_time = interval(start_date, end_date))

times %>% mutate(hol_dur = hol_time %% days(1))
```

Output:

```
  start_date end_date   hol_time                       hol_dur                       
  <chr>      <chr>      <Interval>                     <Interval>                    
1 2020-02-27 2020-03-17 2020-02-27 UTC--2020-03-17 UTC 2020-03-17 UTC--2020-03-17 UTC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `/` instead:

```
> times$hol_time/days(1)
[1] 19
```